# Why subscribe on BehaviourSubject asObservable never fires onComplete?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm using Angular. I have service which I use to store and get data from localstorage. I'm saving BehaviorSubject asObservable(). 
Code below:

```
import { Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationStorageService {

  ModuleTitle = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  currentModuleTitle = this.ModuleTitle.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setModuleId(ModuleId) {
    localStorage.setItem('subModuleId', ModuleId)
    this.ModuleTitle.next(ModuleId);   
  }

  getModuleId() {
    this.ModuleTitle.next(localStorage.getItem('subModuleId'));
    return this.currentModuleTitle;
  }
}
```

Next I'm getting this data using code below:

```
getModuleId() {
  this._navigationStorageService.getModuleId()
    .subscribe(
      subModuleId => {
        this.subModuleId = subModuleId
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      },
      () => console.log("getModuleId"));
}
```

My problem is I want to execute other function when observable is completed but this observable is never completed so I can't do that.

() => console.log("getModuleId") is not showing the message.

How can I solve this?

At the other part of my App I'm using Observable to get HttpClient request and it works fine. I mean onComplete fires as it should to.

I have tried using .finally()

```
    getModuleId() {
    this._navigationStorageService.getModuleId()
        .finally(() => console.log("getModuleId"))
        .subscribe(
            subModuleId => {
                this.subModuleId = subModuleId
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error)
            },
            () => console.log("getModuleId"));
}
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: I think you must call complete by hand as an observable does not know when it's completed. See [rxjs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observable) for more information. Else just call the function you want when subscribing to the value delivered by the observable, like got a new value -> call that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subjects complete only when you tell them to complete by calling `complete()`.

The question here is what you're trying to achieve. It's possible that you never want the Subject to complete so you'll never call `this.ModuleTitle.complete()` but you still want to send the `complete` notification to "consumers" of `currentModuleTitle`.

This means that you can use `take(1)` operator that takes just one value and immediately completes the chain (no need to use `asObservable`).

```
currentModuleTitle = this.ModuleTitle.take(1);
```

Now every time you do `currentModuleTitle.subscribe()` you'll receive one value immediately and complete. Be aware that `BehaviorSubject` emits its stored value first so all consumers of `currentModuleTitle` will in fact receive just the cached value and no further updates.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bad the Observable object. When you use the getModuleId() method for get an item of localStorage you have this value instantly then the Observable not has sense.

```
 import { Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationStorageService {

  ModuleTitle = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  currentModuleTitle = this.ModuleTitle.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  setModuleId(ModuleId) {
    localStorage.setItem('subModuleId', ModuleId)
  }

  getModuleId(id) {
    return localStorage.getItem(id);
  }
}
```